# CoreData schema changes not deploying to CloudKit when using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

Hi I am using CoreData in an app in development environment, and when I change my models the schema changes occur automatically in CoreData, as they should. But for some reason when I look at the CloudKit Dashboard these schema changes are not getting reflected there. I deleted 2 attributes, and they got deleted in the CoreData schema but not on the CloudKit schema.

Anyone know why could this be? Do I have to do anything specially to make schema changes in CoreData reflect in CloudKit? This is all happening in the development environment, this is not related to issues regarding Development-Production migrations.

Also, for some reason I can't delete these, or any, attributes (or as they are called in CloudKit, fields) in the CloudKit dashboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer if anybody happens to end up here: turns out you can't delete attributes after they've been created in CloudKit.